# finding the "API key"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Google uses different names sometimes for the same element and changes everything frequently.  This is why reading stack overflow posts over time makes little sense.

When I post from my server to FCM I need to pass an "API key".
I successfully converted one app from GCM to FCM by using the "Legacy server key" from the Firebase Settings CloludMessaging page and it works.  The help cloud there says I can continue using this Legacy server key but I should upgrade to the "newest Version"  They don't say what they mean by "newest Version" or where to get it.

I'm now converting a second app to Firebase cloud messaging so I used the Legacy server key for that app but it does not work.  I'm getting "mismatchsenderid".  I don't know why this works in one app and not in the other.

There are "Server key", Legacy server key, Sender ID, Web API Key . . . .

Where can I get the proper "API Key" and exactly what is it called in the firebase console?  What is the "newest version" ???

Answer (score 0):

When using FCM, the API key referred to is always the *Server Key* located just above the *Legacy Server Key* in your Firebase Console -- Project Settings (gear icon) > Cloud Messaging tab (make sure you selected the correct Firebase Project)

[image]

There isn't any documentation explaining the difference between the two (there might be something here on SO, but I haven't found anything yet) that extensively explains the difference between the two. What I *think* though is that the Legacy Server Key makes use of an old setting for GCM -- before, the API key can be retrieved from the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), and devs have the option to select an API Key type (e.g. Server Key, Android Key, Web Key) which worked like any server key. After some time, they enforced the Server Key only limitation.

FCM is constantly changing and improving (any tech service pretty much does that), but currently, to stay on topic, the *API key* that is only needed for FCM to work is the *Server Key*. The *Legacy Server Key* can still be used, but it is strongly advised that developers use the new Server Key.